# alguien puede explicarme este codigo ajax - jquery?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Nuevamente recurro al grupo.. no estoy entendiendo como funciona este código ajax y me gustaría q alguno pueda darme una manita.. el código es el siguiente

```
$(document).on("keyup","#mPagar",function(){
    monto = $(this).val();
    $("#btn-agregar-dsc").val(monto);  <<< cargo el valor de mi input como value de mi boton

});

$(document).on("click","#btn-agregar-dsc",function(){
    pago = $(this).val();  <<< aca tomo el valor q se cargo en el btn y cargo en la var pago
    sld = $("input[name='saldo']").val() - pago; <<< resto el valor del saldo  con el valor del pago
    $("#saldo").val(sld); <<< en el input saldo carga el el resultado de la resta
    nComp = $("imput[name='numero']").val(); <<< carga en la var el # documento para imputar el pago
>>aca empieza mi problema<<
    //alert(valor_id);
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: base_url + "movimientos/cobranzas/listCobrXFactura", << aca llamaria al controlador
        type: "POST", << utilizando el metodo post
        dataType: "html", << me imagino que es porq estoy trabajando con un html
        data: {id:nComp}, <<< en carga el # de comprobante 
        success: function(data){ << recibe en data lo que devuelve la función
            $("#tbcobranza tbody").html(data); <<< carga en tbody de la tabla el resultado
        }
    });
});
```

donde se envía a la función del controlador el id del documento que quiero trabajar? y el resto esta bien?? esa función copie de una ejemplo pero no me esta funcionando si alguien pilla algun error y me lo hace saber estaré muy agradecido..

Comment: ¿Te lanza algún error? O solo quieres saber lo que hace el código.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez la vd no lanza ningun error, pero no hace nada la parte del ajax.. por eso me gustaria entender el codigo para ver donde puede estar mi posible error.. MUchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo!!

Comment: Te hace falta definir las variables, utiliza var o let

Answer (score 0):

A tu controlador le está llegando una variable id con valor ncomp. Lo indicas aqui -> data: {id:nComp}
En ese controlador devuelve un json para responder.
Utiliza

`success: function(data,res)
{
  console.log(res)
}`

Y ahí verás tu respuesta.